# JavaScript assigning array key results in duplicated results

Tags: javascript, arrays

Not sure if this is a bug or I'm missing something.

I understand the logic isn't great here, but I noticed a weird behavior with the following code.

Here we're just traversing the `data` array and creating a new array with the same values as the result. The resulting array should match the original `data` array.

```js
let data = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
];

let array1 = [], array2 = [];

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    let row = data[i];
    //array1 = [];
    console.log(`Loop ${i}\n`);

    for(let j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {

        let value = data[i][j];
        
        array1[j] = value;
        array2[i] = array1;

        console.log(`i: ${i}, j: ${j}`)
        console.log('array1', array1)    
        console.log('array2', array2, "\n")
    }    
    console.log(`----\n`);
}

console.log(array2)
```

However the end result is this:

```js
[ [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ], [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ] ]
```

By uncommenting the line `//array1 = [];` the result then is correct

```js
[ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ] ]
```

During the loop `array2[i] = array1;` should only effect the `i` key of `array2`. However if `i = 1` it will still effect the values of `array2[0]`. Why?

Comment: You keep (re)using the **same** `array1` so there is only one inner array, and as you add multiple references to it in `array2`, they all print the same. By uncommenting that assignment, a new `[]` is created (it is each time a new array).

Comment: You can move `array2[i] = array1;` outside of the inner for loop

Comment: you need to `push` into those new arrays